# How to print specific array entry using variable for position e.g. $array[$x]

Tags: php

With help from others on here, I've got a nested loop on the go that pull a list of months from one sql table and then, for each of those months, it goes through an events table and pulls the respective events.

Table structures are along the lines of:

MonthTable

```
ID  | MonthShort |  MonthLong
1 | 2012Oct | October 2012
2 | 2012Sep | September 2012
```

---

EventTable

```
ID | MonthID | Event | Guests | Adults | Children
1 | 1 | Wedding | 200 | 150 | 50
2 | 1 | Bar Mitzvah | 100 | 50 | 50
3 | 1 | Funeral | 100 | 50 | 50 
4 | 2 | Birthday | 50 | 30 | 20 
5 | 2 | Birthday | 300 | 200 | 100
6 | 2 | Wedding | 200 | 180 | 20
```

My loop works so that it populates menu A with all available months, then populates menu B with all of the events for that month. You can then click on the event and it displays the relevant information - this is where I'm a bit stuck.

The arrays I've got are similar to the following, the guests array is what I'm trying out atm:

```
$events = array();
$months = array();
$guests = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $months[$row["MonthID"]] = $row["MonthLong"];
  $events[$row["MonthID"]][] = $row["Event"];
  $guests[$row["MonthID"]][] = $row["Guests"];
}
```

I use a foreach to populate menu B with ($events[$x] as $event). The screen for each event will have an entry similar to the following and this is what I'd like to do (obviously I know this won't work bu it should serve for illustrative purposes):

echo ' Number of guests: ' . print_r($guests[$x])

With guests and events both on the same counter I though it would allow me to print the array entry in the relevant position.

So what I'd like it if you click on "`October 2012`" and then select "`Funeral`", the screen would say:

**Number of guests: 100**

There are actually several dozen records per event but no point going into all of them...

Apologies for the rambling and if this makes no sense! I'm new to PHP and am only really stuck on this bit.

SQL query is built on the following:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    a.id, b.id AS monthId, a.event, b.monthshort, b.monthlong
  FROM
    events_table_name AS a
  INNER JOIN
    month_table_name AS b ON b.id = a.monthId
  ORDER BY
    b.id, a.id ASC
  ";
```

Comment: Change `$months[$row["MonthID"]] = $row["MonthLong"];` to `$months[$row["MonthID"]][] = $row["MonthLong"];`

Comment: Could you let us know what the SQL query is? It looks like it's a join, but that will affect the final code.

Comment: Thanks, query added. I may have budged a fix based on something Baba said, I took the [] away from guests and now I can echo out by simply doing . $guests[$x] .

Comment: Apologies, I'm also pulling guests, adults, children, etc. in the above SELECT. This was the query that was suggested by the person who originally helped me with the nested menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make use of the index in the foreach statement. I mean

```
foreach ($events[$x] as $i => $event) {
    ...
    echo ' Number of guests: ' . print_r($guests[$x][$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work to populate guests although I've not tried with the other fields yet.

Comment: Should I use - $adults[$row["MonthID"]][] = $row["Adults"]; and so on for every field? Or is there a more optimal way of doing it?

Comment: I think this should be legal: `foreach (array_keys($row) as $key) {$lcKey = strtolower($key); ${lcKey}[$row["MonthID"]][] = $row[$key];}`

Comment: thanks again, one last question, if I may? I notice that if I do echo ' there were: ' . print_r($guests[$x][$i]) . ' guests'; I get a "1" on the end of the returned number? It's only if I follow up with another . '.... If I put the array value at the end of my echo it's fine?

Comment: Nvm, I simply put them on three separate lines and the "1" goes away... You're a lifesaver!!

Comment: Correction to my last comment: change ${lcKey} by ${$lcKey}. Your last question: print_r returns true which is cast to 1 and prints to stdout. print_r accepts a 2nd parameter to change this behaviour. Use print_r($guests[$x][$i], true)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a different data structure in PHP. How about this? You might have to change your SQL query to get it, but this is the data structure I'd aim for:

```
$months = array(
    '1' =>  array(
        'long' => 'October 2012',
        'events' => array(
            '1' => array(
                'name' => 'Wedding',
                'guests' => '200'   
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'name' => 'Bar Mitzvah',
                'guests' => '100'
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'name' => 'Funeral',
                'guests' => '100'
            )
        )
    ),
     '2' => array(
        // etc.
    )
);
```

This way, you're able to look up a month; for each month, its events; for each event, its attendance and name.

Comment: Thanks, for neatness sake I will certainly look at something like this!